# How to plot color range plot with data?

Tags: plotting, color, list-manipulation

[image]

I have some data and want to plot it like in the figure mentioned but unable to do it. The code I tried is written below but it is not giving any plot.
If anyone can resolve this is most welcome.

```
ee = 1;
P0 = .3;
k1 = 0.1;
kd = 0.2;
gma = 0.01;
alpa = 0.5;
X1 = -(c1/2 + P0)/(2*a1 - I/2*(k1 + kd) + alpa);
a1 = c1/Sqrt[2]*X1;
X2 = (I*ee/Sqrt[2] + (c1/Sqrt[2]*a1))/(2*(I*k1/2 - a1) + alpa);
b1 = Evaluate[Log[Abs[X2]^2/(2*Abs[X1])^4]];
GraphicsRow[{ListDensityPlot[Table[b1[c1 a1], {c1, 0, 5, 0.1}, {a1, -4, 4, 1}], 
ColorFunction -> Hue]}]
```

Comment: ListLinePlot creates only line plots. The one that you have shown is more of a contour plot. Try looking into ListContourPlot or ListDensityPlot

Comment: @Sâu Now it is showing an error like, ````ListDensityPlot::arrayerr: Table[{{0,-2,0},{0,-5,1},{0,-2,2},{0,-1,3},{0,0,4}} {{1,-1,0},{1,-3,1},{1,-1,2},{1,0,3},{1,0,4}},{{2,-1,0},{2,-2,1},{2,-2,2},{2,-1,3}},{{3,0,0},{3,-1,1},{3,-2,2},{3,-3,3},{3,-2,4}},{{4,0,0},{4,-1,1},{4,-2,2},{4,-3,3},{4,-1,4}},{{-1,-2,0},{-1,-1,1},{-1,-2,2},{-1,-2,3},{-1,-1,4}},{{-2,-2,0},{-2,-1,1},{-2,-2,2},{-2,-2,3},{-2,-1,4}},{{-3,-2,0},{-3,-1,1},{-3,-2,2},{-3,-2,3},{-3,-1,4}},{{-4,-2,0},{-4,-1,1},{-4,-2,2},{-4,-2,3},{-4,-1,4}}] must be a valid array. >>

Comment: You are getting this error because the way your data is structured does not make any sense. Can you please edit the question and give more information on what A1, B1, and C1 represent? Also, it seems like you are new to Mathematica. I suggest looking at the documentation on how lists and arrays work in Mathematica.

Comment: Actually, the code is this and I want to plot like the above graph.                        
`ee = 1;
P0 = .3;
k1 = 0.1;
kd = 0.2;
gma = 0.01;
alpa = 0.5;
X1 = -(c1/2 + P0)/(2*a1 - I/2*(k1 + kd) + alpa);
a1 = c1/Sqrt[2]*X1;
X2 = (I*ee/Sqrt[2] + (c1/Sqrt[2]*a1))/(2*(I*k1/2 - a1) + alpa);
b1 = Evaluate[Log[Abs[X2]^2/(2*Abs[X1])^4]];
GraphicsRow[{ListDensityPlot[
   Table[b1[c1 a1], {c1, 0, 5, 0.1}, {a1, -4, 4, 1}], 
   ColorFunction -> Hue]}]`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the extra information in the question itself so that other users can also help.

Comment: @Sâu I have edited the question.

Comment: The equations are too complicated and this question isn't about solving them. Please simplify the equations as much as posible or provide a simple MWE what you want to get.

Comment: @Sâu I want to plot b1 with respect to a1 and c1.

Comment: Your definitions are circular, e.g., `a1` depends on `X1` but `X1` depends on `a1`. This generates a recursion depth error.